# fail to pass a value in constructor

Tags: library

I'm making a JSON lib dedicated for my own needs, based on `ArduinoJSON` v6.

I try to define `StaticJsonDocument<_docSize> doc` in a parametric way but I get this error and I cant find the reason for it:

```
/Users/guy/git/Arduino/libraries/myJSON/myJSON.cpp: In constructor 'myJSON::myJSON(char*, int, bool)':
/Users/guy/git/Arduino/libraries/myJSON/myJSON.cpp:12:28: sorry, unimplemented: use of the value of the object being constructed in a constant expression
         StaticJsonDocument<_docSize> doc;
                            ^
/Users/guy/git/Arduino/libraries/myJSON/myJSON.cpp:12:36: error: 'this' is not a constant expression
         StaticJsonDocument<_docSize> doc;
                                    ^
/Users/guy/git/Arduino/libraries/myJSON/myJSON.cpp:12:36: note: in template argument for type 'unsigned int' 
/Users/guy/git/Arduino/libraries/myJSON/myJSON.cpp:12:41: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
         StaticJsonDocument<_docSize> doc;
                                         ^
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

I paste only relevant part of the code

`myJSON.h` :

```
#ifndef myJSON_h
#define myJSON_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "FS.h"


class myJSON
{
private:
int _docSize=100;
bool useSerial;
char _filename[30];

public:
myJSON(char *filename, int docsize, bool useserial=false);
bool file_exists();//char *file=_filename);
bool file_remove();
bool format ();

};
#endif
```

`myJSON.cpp`:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "myJSON.h"
#include "FS.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>


myJSON::myJSON(char *filename, int docsize, bool useserial) {

        _docSize = docsize;
        useSerial = useserial;

        StaticJsonDocument<_docSize> doc;

        if (useSerial) {
                Serial.begin(9600);
        }
        if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
                }
        }
        else{
                sprintf(_filename,"%s",filename);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class that uses `<...>` is called a *template* class.  That class uses a form of substitution at compile time to create a *concrete* class with those values and tokens substituted.

It is then that *concrete* class that is used to instantiate your object(s).

However, you are trying to use a runtime variable to convert a *template* class into a *concrete* class, and that can't be done at compile time - and there is no such thing as a *runtime template* in C++.

You need to re-think your implementation methodology.

Comment: thank you for explaining.  My intention is to to be able to define size of JSON buffer- is there a way doing so the way I need it ?

Comment: I would suggest create the JSON object outside your class and pass that object to the constructor. Without knowing what ArduinoJSON does with the buffer and how it's instantiated I can't comment.

Comment: OK-  that it was a good enough workaround. TNX